# Symfony2 and GoDaddy error message with incorrect information

Tags: mysql, symfony

I recently uploaded a Symfony2 project to GoDaddy and I'm having trouble accesing it because I get the message:

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)
```

Obviously the message is clear, so I checked and rechecked my parameters.yml, and the message don't even match what I have there, which I have changed several times to try to fix. This is my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: database1
    database_user: database1user
    database_password: mytestpassword
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: RandomTokenThatWillBeChanged
    debug_toolbar: true
    debug_redirects: false
    use_assetic_controller: true
```

So, the error message doesn't tell me what is my real problem, or it is loading the parameters from some cached version that I haven't found yet. Any ideas of what else could cause or where could a cached version of this data be?

Comment: Does this exception occur in the dev, test or prod environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the best practice when developing a Symfony application is to
>   make it configurable via a parameters.yml file. It contains
>   information such as the database name, the mailer hostname, and custom
>   configuration parameters.
>
> As those parameters can be different on your local machine, your
>   testing environment, your production servers, and even between
>   developers working on the same project, it is not recommended to store
>   it in the project repository. Instead, the repository should contain a
>   paramaters.yml.dist file with sensible defaults that can be used as a
>   good starting point for everyone.
>
> Then, whenever a developer starts working on the project, the
>   parameters`.yml file must be created by using the parameters.yml.dist
>   as a template. That works quite well, but whenever a new value is
>   added to the template, you must remember to update the main parameter
>   file accordingly.
>
> As of Symfony 2.3, the Standard Edition comes with a new bundle that
>   automates the tedious work. Whenever you run composer install, a
>   script creates the parameters.yml file if it does not exist and allows
>   you to customize all the values interactively. Moreover, if you use
>   the --no-interaction flag, it will silently fallback to the default
>   values.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file

So, is it not possible that your paramaters.yml is overwritten by paramaters.yml.dist?

---

You can also try to completely clear the cache
**In Dev:**

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

**In Production:**

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: Thanks! Removing the parameters.yml.dist and clearing the cache in production environment solved It... although I'm not quite sure why, since parameters.yml.dist had the same data as the main one. But still, It worked ^^