# fail to make connection with mysql symfony2 doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with database connection in symfony2.7
my config.yml is

```
            driver:    pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
```

and my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
database_host: 192.168.123.11
database_port: 3306
database_name: test
database_user: root
database_password: xxx
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: localhost
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

my server is

```
  192.168.123.11
  password xyz
```

user data base account is

```
 account name: root 
 password   :  xxx
```

all user privileges assigned to this user. Now when I run this it give me error

```
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                    
 An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'ap-hof.swisstr  
 affic.local' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

any idea where I am doing mistake? i can access my server pluse user name access through ssh...

Comment: Try to using in config.yml - host: "%database_host%" instead of host: "%database_I host%"  And in parameters.yml  I think database_port: null will work no need to give port in case of mysql

Comment: Typo: `"%database_I host%"`

Comment: Sound to me like the server is blocking access. Check the access privileges to the the DB. I've not seen the 'Host is not allowed' error before but that's what causes the 'user not allowed' errors

Comment: i make it null the port. and other typo fix. but still the same problem...

Comment: As @Horaland said the problem is on db server side (192.168.123.11).

Answer (score 1):

You must authorize remote access root on your mysql server.
try to delete this line in your my.cnf file :

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

For authorize connection root without local

Comment: i check the my.cnf i did not find any line like that . i found this text only in it                                                                                                           datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
character-set-server=utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: I found solution. basically it was not due to not mysql but my previous buil application with postgresql driver and certainly once i change the driver it could not build up ... here is the link for the solution..               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044804/symfony2-and-godaddy-error-message-with-incorrect-information